# Append $id to post slug on create in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slug, laravel-5.6

I'm creating a blog post from a form using Laravel, and passing the title and body through to the `create` method in the `PostsController`.

The slug has to be unique, so although the following works, it fails when I use a duplicate title.

I intended on appending the `$post->id` to the slug, so `this-is-the-post-title` would become `this-is-the-post-title-12`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use Session;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class PostController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request) {
  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'body'  => 'required'
  ]);

  $post = new Post;
  $post->title = $request->input('title');
  $post->body = $request->input('body');
  $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title'), '-');
  $post->save();

  Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved!');

  return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

My initial thought was to concatenate `$post->id` to the end of the slug, but it doesn't work.

I'm assuming that this is because the `id` isn't assigned until the `save()`?

Is there a way to get the id that is going to be used?

I thought of just returning the number of rows in the db, and adding one, but that would fail if two people posted at the same time.

(I'm fairly new to Laravel and taught myself PHP, so this may be glaringly obvious/simple, but any help is appreciated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save first then update later:

```
$post = \DB::transaction(function() use($request) {
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->slug = uniqid(); //to avoid unique column conflict, it will be overwritten
    $post->save();

    $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title').' '.$post->id, '-');
    $post->save();

    return $post;
});
```

Comment: If the slug column has a unique constraint, you have to be careful what you put in as `'anything'`. Apart from that, this should work.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I did this originally, but it failed. I now realise that I used 'test post' as the title, and it failed as I already had a `test-post` slug in the db. Having truncated the table, it means that I won't be able to have 'test-post' as a slug at all, as it will automatically have the id appended.

Comment: Reverted back to the answer above, it threw an error if I titled a post say "post 2" and there was already a post with the slug `post-2`

Comment: Thanks you so much